# How do I remove the accompanying feature numbers?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

For this program as below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.set_printoptions(formatter='float')
np.random.seed(1)
dataset = pd.read_csv("/Users/Akshita/Desktop/EE660/donor_raw_data_medmean.csv",header=None)
print("Number of samples: {0}".format(dataset.shape[0]))
print("Number of features: {0}".format((dataset.shape[1])-1))

# Separate data and label
X_label = dataset[:][0]
feature_number = list(range(1,61))
X_data = dataset[feature_number]

meanVectors = []

for c in list(range(2)):
    meanVectors.append(np.mean(X_data[X_label==c], axis=0))
    print('Mean Vector class {0}:{1}' .format(c,(meanVectors[c])))
```

My output is:

```
Number of samples: 19373
Number of features: 60
Mean Vector class 0:
1        70.719718
2        60.037559
3         0.107512
..
..
58       66.634272
59       13.971254
60        4.748826
dtype: float64
Mean Vector class 1:
1        75.575087
2        60.844005
3         0.145518
..
..
58       71.436554
59       12.092189
60        6.006985
```

How can I get the output a simple `[75.575087, 60.844005, 0.145518...6.006985]`
and the same for the next?

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644656/how-to-print-dataframe-without-index

Comment: Clarification: Do you want these displayed in this format "[75.575087, 60.844005, 0.145518...6.006985]" or in the format that is currently being displayed, but without the index numbers on the left edge?

Comment: @furas Let me try the link and let you kind folks know if it worked.

Comment: I have tried every possible combination to patch "index= False" to an existing statement in the code. Python gives me different errors for all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like meanVectors[c] should return a Series object, which has a tolist function.

```
for c in list(range(2)):
    meanVectors.append(np.mean(X_data[X_label==c], axis=0))
    print('Mean Vector class {0}:{1}' .format(c,(meanVectors[c].tolist())))
```

Comment: Is there no way for meanVector to change its type to [75.575087, 60.844005, 0.145518...6.006985] instead of changing the display to the desired type?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by ..."meanVector to change its type" versus "...change the display to the desired type".  meanVector[c].tolist() gives a type of list, but it does not alter the original object's type.