# How to stop outputting row numbers in Django Pandas

Tags: python, django, pandas

The dataframes in Pandas contain column name and row name.How can I stop outputting the row name? I have found method called itertuples where you can set the index to False but that does not seem to work.

The input is a csv file and the output is a xlsx file with sheets. Each sheet contains row numbers right now but those need to disappear.

See comments for answer. This worked for me:

```
PandasDataFrame.to_excel(PandasWriter, sheet_name='Source', index=False)
```

Comment: Why is this a problem? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just don't want the row numbers in my output. That's all. I'm converting a csv file into a xlsx file and the output needs to be according to a predefined template.

Comment: @Andy that will output a very long string which is not what the OP is after, they want their output to just pretty print the values only without index values

Comment: I'm trying Andys suggestion but that does not seem to work for me. Printing to a string is not an option just as EdChum stated.

Comment: I see that Andy has disappeared. He's answer was actually semi-right. The answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644656/how-to-print-dataframe-without-index is not exactly right but the method to_string has similar attributes as method that I have to use to_excel. The following works for me "PandasDataFrame.to_excel(PandasWriter, sheet_name='Source', index=False)". Thanks @Andy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me (from the comments):

`PandasDataFrame.to_excel(PandasWriter, sheet_name='Source', index=False)`