# pandas - groupby column with multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to display the users that have used a value.

```
import pandas as pd
user = ['alice', 'bob', 'tim', 'alice']
val = [['a','b','c'],['a'],['c','d'],['a','d']]
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': user, 'val': val})

user    val
'alice'      [a, b, c]
'bob'        [a]
'tim'        [c, d]
'alice'      [a, d]
```

Desired output:

```
val     users
a      [alice,bob]
b      [alice]
c      [alice,tim]
d      [alice,tim]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1**
Reshape your data -

```
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'val' : list(chain.from_iterable(df.val.tolist())), 
    'user' : df.user.repeat(df.val.str.len())
})
```

**Step 2**
Use `groupby` + `apply` + `unique`:

```
df.groupby('val').user.apply(lambda x: x.unique().tolist())
```

```
val
a    [alice, bob]
b         [alice]
c    [alice, tim]
d    [tim, alice]
Name: user, dtype: object
```

Comment: It is not the same as OP's desired output.

Comment: Shouldn't row 'c' and 'd' be `[1, 3]` (User 1 and 3 have values 'c' and 'd'), but your codes give `[1, 1]`?

Comment: I want to show the actual users. One second let me update my output. The users as numbers are confusing, that's my fault.

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach.

```
df2 = (df
       .set_index('user')
       .val
       .apply(pd.Series)
       .stack()
       .reset_index(name='val')  # Reshape the data
       .groupby(['val'])
       .user
       .apply(lambda x: sorted(set(x))))  # Show users that use the value
```

Output:

```
print(df2)
# val
# a    [alice, bob]
# b         [alice]
# c    [alice, tim]
# d    [alice, tim]
# Name: user, dtype: object
```

Comment: @qrs If performance is important, you may want to take another look at the other answers

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Would you mind telling us why your code is faster?

Comment: Sure, no  worries. `apply(pd.Series)` is generally considered very slow. I learned this the hard way :)

Answer (score 1):

I think need:

```
df2 = (pd.DataFrame(df['val'].values.tolist(), index=df['user'].values)
         .stack()
         .reset_index(name='val')
         .groupby('val')['level_0']
         .unique()
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={'level_0':'user'})
     )
print(df2)
  val          user
0   a  [alice, bob]
1   b       [alice]
2   c  [alice, tim]
3   d  [tim, alice]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough reputation to write this as a comment, but this question has the answer:
[How to print dataframe without index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644656/how-to-print-dataframe-without-index)

basically, change the last line to:

```
print(df2.to_string(index=False))
```

Comment: No, that is isn't it.