# How to concatenate string from integers?

Tags: python, string, pandas, concatenation

I'm very new to python.

How do I get a string like this:

```
53 (46.49 %)
```

But, I'm getting this:

```
1    53 (1    46.49 %)
```

I'm trying to get the last value from the table count and the proportion (i'm not sure what it's called in python)

```
table = pd.value_counts(data[var].values, sort=False)
prop_table = (table/table.sum() * 100).round(2)

num = table[[1]].to_string()
prop = prop_table[[1]].to_string()

test = num + " (" + prop + " %)"
```

but, it puts `1` before displaying the number.

Comment: Can we have a reproducible example of the DataFrame `data`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print dataframe without index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644656/how-to-print-dataframe-without-index). Try `table[[1]].to_string(index=False)`

Comment: or just remove the extra `[]` so `num = table[1].to_string()`

Comment: @Zev, Thank you. That was it. I use R most of the times, but I'm making an effort to learn and use Python more.