# Is it possible to exclude index column from view in Dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, formatting, rank

I want to exclude the Indexcolumn from the view of a Dataframe:
I sort the whole dataframe based on the values (in decending order) and assign ranks.
It perfectly works, however the indexcolumn is a bit misleading (especially in the ranking).
I already tried to replace the Indexcolumn and used the column Rank as an index by using

> df.set_index('Rank', inplace=True)

However, the sorting is then suspended and I may get a key Error if 2 persons (like here) have the same Rank.
My code is:

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

names = ['Tim', 'Tom', 'Sam', 'Kyle']
values = [2, 4, 5, 4]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': names,'Values': values})
columns = ["Name", "Values"]
df['Rank'] = df['Values'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
df.sort_values(by="Rank", ascending=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print pandas DataFrame without index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644656/how-to-print-pandas-dataframe-without-index)

Comment: Tried it already. It is working but the format is changing, I still need it as a  table format

Comment: You could always sort_index() if you want after set_index()

But I would just consider reordering your columns and reset_index() to get a more reasonable output

Comment: I tried the sort_index() already, for some reason it is not working. But I will try to use the reset_index(), Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most (possibly all?) of the pandas `to_...` methods take the `index` argument. If you set it to `False` the index won't be shown. If you really want the pretty HTML output in Jupyter then do

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(df.sort_values(by="Rank", ascending=True).to_html(index=False))
```