# how do i remove the index col from a series?

Tags: pandas

how do i modify my series to give the out i want?

```py
dfloss['net'].head()
```

Output was

```py
2326   -99275.0
3795   -1900853.0
3857   -1589759.0
3941   -1234893.0
4038   -1992320.0
Name: net, dtype: float64
```

the output i want is

```py
-99275.0
-1900853.0
-1589759.0
-1234893.0
-1992320.0
Name: net, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Pandas series always have indexes. You can use `series.reset_index(drop=True)` to have the default range index. Or see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644656/how-to-print-pandas-dataframe-without-index) if you only want to print the series without index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Quang Hoang said in their reply, pandas Series (and DataFrames) always have indices. You can easily access the not explicitly indexed underlying numpy-array via the .values attribute though.

If you're just concerned about the output, try something like this:

```py
for x in df.values:
    print(x)
```

If you just want the first few, you can slice the .values array like any other:

```py
for x in df.values[:5]:
    print(x)
```