# How to print a dataframe without the name of the columns and the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe without columns names and when I print it I get a row with numbers, how can I print without this row? I have the same problem with the index, how can I print without index and columns?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print pandas DataFrame without index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644656/how-to-print-pandas-dataframe-without-index)

Answer (score 3):

See [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) for some more info on using the `to_string()` function in pandas.

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

To hide the index and the column headers:

```
print(df.to_string(index=False, header=False))
```

Comment: Thank you! I what about the columns? as I don't have header, how can I do to avoid the row with numbers that I get when I print?

Comment: print(df.to_string(index=False, header=False))

Comment: Or if you want to set your own column headers you can set header = list of strings