# How to remove index column when reading with read_csv in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

We are trying to read a sample simple csv file using pandas in python as follows -

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')

print(df)

[image]

We need df by removing below red highlighted index column -

[image]

We have tried multiple ways by passing parameters but no luck.

Please help me in this issue!!

Comment: what do you mean by remove index? Pandas will naturally assign an index if none is supplied.

Answer (score 4):

A dataframe requires having some kind of index as part of the structure.

If you want to simply print the output without the index you can use the approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32662331/14080446), with Python 3 syntax:

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

but it will not have the nice dataframe rendering in Jupyter as you have in your example.

If you want to avoid pandas outputting the index when writing *to* a CSV file you can use the option `index=False`, for example:

```
df.to_csv('example.csv', index=False)
```

This will avoid creating the index column in the saved CSV file.

Answer (score 3):

add `index_col=False`

```
pd.read_csv('path.csv',index_col=False)
```

or remove index from dataframe

`df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

Comment: setting index_col=False worked for me. However, I got a warning that Length of header or names does not match the length of data. Any idea what's that about?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I tried `index_col=False`, and `index_col=None`, but none worked.
But `index_col=0` worked. 
So do like this when reading a file.
`df = pd.read_csv('yourfilename.csv', index_col=0)`