# how to hide the 1st column in pandas dataframe which shows serial number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [1, 2, 3], 'C': [4, 5, 6]})

   B  C
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

I want to hide the serial number column. How to approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print pandas DataFrame without index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644656/how-to-print-pandas-dataframe-without-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```