# How to remove the index in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I am trying to make a simple scheduler with pandas datafram. When calling the pandas.loc function for a specific element in the dataframe it outputs the element with the index.

```
df.loc[df['days'] == 'tuesday','task']
```

This is the output

```
'0    Go for a run'
```

As i want to use the output as a string, is there a way to remove the index. Or a different function to use. What i want the output to be is just -

```
'Go for a run'
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['days'] == 'tuesday','task'][0]`?

Answer (score 0):

As per this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644656/how-to-print-pandas-dataframe-without-index) maybe try this:

```
print(df.loc[df['days'] == 'tuesday','task'].to_string(index=False))
```

Hope it works!