# How to remove index from DataFrame output?

Tags: python, pandas

I've created a DataFrame and getting index in output. I'm unable to find a way to hide these index in the output.

```
def create_dataframe(k,v):
  
  a= pd.DataFrame(v, columns=k)       
  return a

k = ["Employee ID", "Name", "Salary"]
v = [["1446","Ashish", "80"],["1447","Priya", "70"], ["1448","Riya", "90"]]

create_dataframe(k,v)
```

Output:

```
    Employee ID Name    Salary
    0   1446    Ashish  80
    1   1447    Priya   70
    2   1448    Riya    90
```

I can use `a.style.hide_index()`, however, with that my DataFrame will be changed to a "Styler" object and I don't want that.

`index=False` doesn't work either.

Can someone please check to point the issue and explain by correcting the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print pandas DataFrame without index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644656/how-to-print-pandas-dataframe-without-index)

Comment: Not exactly, it talks about tabulating the DataFrame and/or using styler which I'm not planning to. I'm sure I'm missing something basic just not able to spot it

Comment: try `df.to_string(index=False)`

Comment: @sagar1025 It will covert my DataFrame to string don't want that to happen

Comment: It might help to describe your use case. Why does it matter if the output is `Styler` / `to_string` / `to_html`? If you want the default dataframe css but without a visible index, you could set the index to empty strings: `df.set_axis([''] * len(df))`

Comment: what is the problem with index? pandas dataframes are  index aligned. what do you intend to do without the index?